# Analysing oscillatory motion due to constant force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, oscillators

Since few days I have been writing a paper on oscillatory motion and after defining the oscillatory motion as

> Periodic motion executed by a particle in the absence of any non-conservative force and in between two positions a.k.a extreme positions where particle has max. potential energy and zero kinetic energy with a position in between the two extreme positions where particle has minimum potential energy with max. kinetic energy a.k.a mean position.

Actually this looks less like a definition and more like an explanation but I tried to make it as short as possible without depriving it of the main information. And the reason I shared this definition, which was created by me after thinking of several cases, is because I want to know that if there is any other system which has a particle executing oscillatory motion and it violates any of the rules mentioned in my definition.
Now, in my paper the next thing I was to write was about Simple Harmonic Motion (S.H.M.) which was to be started on the basis of the relation between Potential energy and displacement (as I used the energy point of view in my definition too) $$U = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$ But I thought of a rather simpler relation which was $$U = k|x|$$
and I didn't know that this was going to be harder to analyze than the S.H.M. itself. So using the relation between Force and Potential energy $$F(x) = -\frac{dU}{dx}$$ I computed the force in the above case to be $$F(x) = -k\,\mathbb{Sgn}(x)$$ where $\mathbb{Sgn}(x)$ denotes the signum function. And the above equation can be written as (assuming the mass of the particle to be $m$) $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{-k}{m}\,\mathbb{Sgn}(x)$$ And here comes the problem for me as I don't know how to proceed further this as I don't have any knowledge of Differential Equations (and this is a second order differential equation) or maybe it can be solved using Fourier Series.
Any help or idea on how to proceed further, to calculate the Equation of motion of particle executing oscillatory motion, will be greatly appreciated.
Also as a side note, with some simple analysis I found that the velocity time graph of the above motion will look like

[image]

This is just for representation purpose.

Comment: The equation of motion is the differential equation that you wrote. And you solved it, considering your graph. It could be for example a test mass in small oscillations through the hole of a planet in the form of a huge LP record.

Comment: That's a great idea to solve this problem but isn't there any way to solve that differential equation to simpler form in terms of x and t. And for the graph, I don't have an equation of that graph so I don't think it's of any use in analysing the situation. I think probably Fourier series would be helpful to get a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where physics trumps mathematics.

If your particle is in the region where $x<0$, then the potential is $U=-kx$ and the force $F=-dU/dx= k$ is constant and positive.  You can then apply the usual solution to motion under constant force:
$$
v_x=v_-+kt \tag{1}
$$
where in this case $v_-$ would be the velocity of your particle as it enters the $x<0$ region.

In the region where $x>0$, you now have $U=kx$ and $F=-k$, again a constant force.  In this region, you now have
$$
v_x=v_+-kt \tag{2}
$$
where $v_+$ is the velocity of your particle as it enters the $x>0$ region.

This explains your $v$ vs $t$ graph: for the portion of the motion described by (1), the slope of the curve is constant everywhere  and positive, while for the portion described by (2), the slope is the same constant but negative.

You could further integrate in each region to get
$x_\pm(t)=x_0+v_\pm t \mp \frac{k}2 t^2$ if you care, where $x_+$ is for the region $x>0$ and $x_-$ for the region $x<0$ .  The minor difficulty will be that, since $x(t)$ is continuous, you will have to match $x_-(t)$ and $x_+(t)$ at $x=0$ because the particle has a single value of $x$ at that point, so that both of your solution must give you this value.

You need to divide your solution in two regions because your potential is discontinuous at $x=0$: as a result the motions in each regions must be solved separately.  The motion will be periodic because there is a time $T$ so that $x(t)=x(t+T)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have one last question that why is it so that the discontinuity of my potential energy function doesn't allow any one single equation to be derived that can describe the whole motion ?

Comment: this is because the equations of motion (as you have written) are differential equations, and the derivative of $U$ is not well defined at $x=0$. Thus you cannot expect to find a single continuous function when the force $dU/dx$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.